# Child ViewController to resize containerView

Tags: ios, swift

My app hierarchy looks something like this [image]

Main view controller (let's call it Controller 1) contains a scrollView, an image and a containerView that points to another viewController and passes data to a tableView.

Controller 1 scroll view is set to be resized correctly with constraints so that containerView can potentially grow in height.

Problem is tableView has data that is loaded dynamically and its size changes, but that does not reflect on containerView. I need my containerView to be notified about tableView new size so it can be resized accordingly too and user can scroll through entire screen, not just within default size of containerView.

I hope that makes sense.

I read about something called [preferredContentSizeDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621351-preferredcontentsizedidchangefor) but I'm not sure how to implement it properly or whether it is even applicable in my situation.

implementing

```
 override func preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer(container: UIContentContainer) {
    super.preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer(container)
    print(container)
}
```

in Controller 1 has not effect

Comment: You could also implement your own delegate method in your ContainerView (set a height constraint) - and call it from your childViewController (TableView) to update height.

Comment: I don't know whether you can test this but, if you didn't have a scroll view at the top level, would there still be a problem?

Comment: Please tell me if I understand your question correctly. Do you want the container to grow as the table view data increases (which will prevent it from scrolling because the tableview's complete data will not overflow) and then when it reaches the total height of the screen, container view should stop growing and tableview will overflow and start scrolling?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but hopefully it'll help someone! I was able to dynamically resize a container to fit its content by doing the following:

Inside my embedded UITableViewController, I added:

```
preferredContentSize.height = tableView.contentSize.height
```

To change the size of the container, I added the embedded view controller as a child of my parent view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? MyTableViewController {
        addChildViewController(destination)
    }
}
```

Finally, I added an outlet for the container and its height constraint, and added the following to the parent view controller:

```
override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {
    super.preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer: container)
    if let child = container as? MyTableViewController {
        containerHeightConstraint.constant = child.preferredContentSize.height
        container.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does "addChildViewController" is a mandatory in order to get 'preferredContentSizeDidChange' to trigger?

Comment: You don't need to cast the childVC, because container.preferredContentSize.height is the value you're looking for.