# Is it possible to have a ContainerView that sizes to its Sub-Stackview size?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I would like to keep my code modular, so I have a ContainerView that points to a sub viewController. I want the size of the ContainerView to change based upon size of the view in sub controller[image] In the simpler case, in the picture above, if I use the StackView I can get the parent purple view to resize if one of the stack view's children is hidden or both.

I want the same thing to happen with the container view (shown as gray view in picture), where if the contained stack view resizes, the parent container view's resizes. I do have an equal height constraint on the containerView.  However, it does not seem to work and I am not sure it is possible. I want it to resize because it blocks clicks to underlying view.

I believe it is similar but different enough to this question since we are talking about stack views., [Child ViewController to resize containerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053731/child-viewcontroller-to-resize-containerview)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

1 - Give your `UIContainerView` top, leading and trailing constraints

2 - Give your `UIContainerView` a Height constraint, with `Priority: Low (250)`... that will be "overridden" by a new constraint added via code.

3 - Setup your child view controller as desired... in this simple case, constrain the stack view to all 4 sides

4 - When the child view has been loaded, set `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on its `.view`, and then add constraints on all 4 sides to the container view

Assuming you have all the constraints properly configured, the container view's height will be determined by its subview (the child VC's view).

Sample code:

```
class AutoSizeContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theContainerView: UIView!

    // so we can reference the embedded VC
    var subVC: SubViewController?

    // this executes before viewDidLoad()
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? SubViewController {
            self.subVC = vc
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make sure subVC was set correctly
        if let vc = self.subVC {
            // constrain child VC's view to container view
            vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.topAnchor),
                vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.leadingAnchor),
                vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.trailingAnchor),

                // this will keep the container view's bottom equal to the child VC's view content
                theContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])
        }

    }

}
```

I've posted a complete example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/AutosizeContainer